# iText 7.0.5 - Forms - NullPointerException when adding a lot of tables with form fields

Tags: itext7

I used Bruno's example (https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-create-fields-table) to add form fields to tables in a newly created document. The example itself works without any problems, but if I want to create 50 tables I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:552)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.getAsArray(PdfDictionary.java:156)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.getAnnotations(PdfPage.java:743)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfAnnotation.getPage(PdfAnnotation.java:427)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.regenerateField(PdfFormField.java:1781)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:1043)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:1004)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:999)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.createText(PdfFormField.java:469)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.createText(PdfFormField.java:410)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.createText(PdfFormField.java:391)
    at CreateFormInTable$MyCellRenderer.draw(CreateFormInTable.java:62)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.drawChildren(TableRenderer.java:1023)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.draw(AbstractRenderer.java:458)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.draw(TableRenderer.java:948)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DocumentRenderer.flushSingleRenderer(DocumentRenderer.java:138)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.processRenderer(RootRenderer.java:349)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.shrinkCurrentAreaAndProcessRenderer(RootRenderer.java:338)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:236)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:109)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:143)
    at CreateFormInTable.manipulatePdf(CreateFormInTable.java:45)
    at CreateFormInTable.main(CreateFormInTable.java:25)
```

I use Java 1.8.0_121 on Windows 8 Enterprise.

The modified `manipulatePdf` method looks like this:

```
protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        Table table = new Table(2);
        Cell cell;
        cell = new Cell().add("Name:");
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new Cell();
        cell.setNextRenderer(new MyCellRenderer(cell, "name" + i));
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new Cell().add("Address");
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new Cell();
        cell.setNextRenderer(new MyCellRenderer(cell, "address" + i));
        table.addCell(cell);
        doc.add(table);
    }
    doc.close();
}
```

The complete example that produces the NPE can be found here: https://github.com/trettstadtnlb/itext-table-form-fields

Has anyone experienced this kind of behaviour or can confirm that this is a bug?

Comment: My guess would be that the original MyCellRenderer was not written to handle something (page splits?) properly when scaling up. I'd have to take a look, rendering has been improved and changed quite a  bit as well in the meantime, so more changes might be in order as well.

Comment: This was a bug in iText 7. It is fixed in 7.1.2 and 7.0.7 versions. The error occurred when some of the PdfFormField instances were created or manipulated while at least one page was already flushed.

Comment: Concerning your `MyCellRenderer`, I'd suggest using `form.addField(field, occupiedArea.getPageNumber());` so the result is independent from the number of pages at the moment of drawing.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to reproduce this behavior in iText 7.0.x using much less content:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

PdfTextFormField field = PdfFormField.createText(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 20), "name", "");
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
form.addField(field);

doc.close();
```

The problem behind this is that for a form field (widget) without an associated page, iText tries to determine the page that widget is on by iterating all document pages and looking up their respective annotation arrays. And it already does so during `createText`, while setting the field value (and updating widget appearances)...

In the code above, though, the previous newly created pages, at least the first one, has already been flushed to the writer and de-initialized in memory. Thus, the loop over the pages tries to retrieve a value from a de-initialized page dictionary, i.e. from a `null Map`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Whether this is a bug in iText or merely an anti-pattern, I don't know.

---

Inspired by @SamuelHuylebroeck's comment I tried both the OP's original code and the simplified code above with `immediateFlush` set to `false`. Indeed, this prevents the exception and the result of the simplified code looks ok. The result of the OP's original code, though, is not as he expects it, the table is built across four pages but all the fields turns up on the last page!

So, in case of form elements created directly (i.e. not via events) setting `immediateFlush` to `false` may be considered a *work-around* (but *not a fix* as the early flushing is an important feature of iText). The general case of form creation is broken, though, unless someone can point out that the code here is an iText 7 anti-pattern and can show how it should be done.

Comment: If this is the root cause of the problem, setting immediate flushing to false should fix the issue. Set immediate flush using one of the overloaded Document constructors (default is set to true)

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck Indeed, without immediate flushing the exception does not occur and a PDF is created. Surely not as expected by the OP but yes, it is created. So even without immediate flushing one should not create tables with fields if the table is split over multiple pages.

Comment: I'd have to look into the source code to see exactly how the form field and its widget are made and added to the document. It might be easy to allow a page reference to be passed during annotation construction. Might