# How to add signature form to an existing pdf (using iText7), so that the output file can be served as a input to pdf (sequential signature)?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, itext7, sequential

I am using iText7 for pdf signature workflow, i followed the samples provided with  [i7js-signatures](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter02). However my requirement is to take an input pdf file, add sequential signatures to it, and further pass it for signature.

i tried splitting up the process in two steps.

1. Take input pdf and add sequential signature panel, in the intermediate_output file.

   ```java
   public void createForm() throws IOException {
       PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(FORM),new PdfWriter(TMP));
       //PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(FORM));
       pdfDoc.addNewPage();
       Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
       Table table = new Table(1);
       table.addCell("Signer 1: Alice");
       table.addCell(createSignatureFieldCell("sig1"));
       table.addCell("Signer 2: Bob");
       table.addCell(createSignatureFieldCell("sig2"));
       table.addCell("Signer 3: Carol");
       table.addCell(createSignatureFieldCell("sig3"));
       doc.add(table);
       doc.close();
   }
   ```
2. Take intermediate_output file and sign it.

While running the step two with output of step 1, i am getting  com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: error.reading.objstm

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: error.reading.objstm
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObjectStream(PdfReader.java:508)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObject(PdfReader.java:1014)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObject(PdfReader.java:533)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfIndirectReference.getRefersTo(PdfIndirectReference.java:128)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfIndirectReference.getRefersTo(PdfIndirectReference.java:132)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfArray.get(PdfArray.java:376)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfArray.get(PdfArray.java:237)
```

Input pdf:

[image: Input pdf]

Intermediate pdf page 1:

[image: Intermediate pdf page 1]

Intermediate pdf page 2:

[image: Intermediate pdf page 2]

Please guide me in case, i am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Can you share an intermediary output file that issue occurs with?

Comment: i updated the description with screen shot's of input and intermediate pdf's, as sought after by @mkl,

Comment: Well, strictly speaking I was asking for the PDFs themselves, not screenshots of them. That been said, though, one issue already becomes apparent in the screen shots: the table is added on page 1 but the fields are added on page 2. This reminds me of a known iText 7 issue in context with form fields. Which iText 7 version exactly are you using? If not the current one (7.1.2), please try again with that one.Furthermore, please show the stack trace of the exception down to a method in your code and include the pivotal part of that method.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, i was using 7.0.0, and changed to 7.1.2 and now that exception is not coming, and Files are generating, yet the issue which you pointed out still exists (table on page 1 and fields are on page 2). Please let me know how can i share/ upload files here.

Comment: *"Please let me know how can i share/ upload files here."* - Unfortunately stack overflow does not provide arbitrary attachment upload. Usually, therefore, one creates a public googledrive or dropbox share with the files in question and posts an URL to it here. If only the pointed out issue remains, though, the actual PDFs here aren't necessary anymore. Where exactly do you want to have the table with the fields? Both on the first or both on the second page?

Comment: I want to append both on the second page ( after the content of input file ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying iText 7 bug/peculiarity is the same as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634291/1729265) where *the table is built across four pages but all the fields turns up on the last page.*

As you clarified, though, in a comment, you want the table and the fields on the last page anyways. Thus, all we need to do is move the table to the last page, too.

This actually is quite simple, merely add an appropriate `AreaBreak` before adding the table:

```
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));
doc.add(table);
```

*([AddSignatureField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/AddSignatureField.java#L81) test `testAddSignaturesInTable`)*

---

You updated your iText version in the context of this question. Meanwhile there have been considerable changes in the table creation code. Thus, you will probably want to also set a width of the signature cell, e.g.

```
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setHeight(50);
cell.setWidth(200);
cell.setNextRenderer(new SignatureFieldCellRenderer(cell, name));
return cell;
```

*([AddSignatureField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/AddSignatureField.java#L103) method `createSignatureFieldCell`)*

Comment: Thanks a Ton, this approach worked and now files are generating as expected. Thanks again :D